# Loading an interface fails

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, com

I'd like to use a COM function : `CreateInstance`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2cy7zfz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

like this

```
IPointer p=NULL;
HRESULT hr=p.CreateInstance(xxx);
```

However I don't have `CLSID` of *xxx* I only know its interface name `ISubPointer`
I can see its interface description inside the tlb file when I view the file with `oleview`. What should I do to use that `CreateInstance` ?

Comment: That's not possible.  An interface is implemented by a coclass.  You must create the class object first, then you can call QueryInterface() to obtain the interface pointer.  Creating the object requires knowing the CLSID or ProgId.  Contact the vendor or author of this type library to ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

1st: a `ClassFactory` ,and

2nd: a helper function to create a pointer.

I found [this](http://tnvbalaji.com/articles/com/comtutorial/):

```
int main()
{
    IMath* pIMath;
    HRESULT hr;

    // 1. Initialize COM Library
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    // 2. Call CoCreateInstance to get the IMath interface pointer
    hr = CoCreateInstance ( __uuidof(CMathComp), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                            __uuidof(IMath), (void**) &pIMath );

    if ( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // 3. Call the interface functions
    int sum = pIMath->Add(1, 3);
    printf("Sum = %d \n", sum);

    int sub = pIMath->Sub(4, 3);
    printf("Sub = %d \n", sub);

    // 4. Release the interface pointer if you are done
    pIMath->Release();

    // 5. Un-Initialize COM Library
    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

Also see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
HRESULT CoCreateInstance(
  _In_   REFCLSID rclsid,
  _In_   LPUNKNOWN pUnkOuter,
  _In_   DWORD dwClsContext,
  _In_   REFIID riid,
  _Out_  LPVOID *ppv
);
```

If you can gather the `CLSID` from OLEVIEW use it, otherwise there must be documentation about this. You can't deliver a component without exposing ist `CLSID`.

Comment: Yes, the document says so too but the truth is I can't find where the desired CLSID is. [I searched everything- people claim the system is running fine]

Comment: Well, did you find it in OLEViewer or did you not?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options for obtaining the class ID of the object you want to create. You can use the OLE Viewer to generate the header files or you can directly import the type library into your source file using the [`#import`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) directive. The [`CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function that you refer to is a non-static member of `_com_ptr_t` and requires you to use an instance of it.

The following example should get you on your way.

```
#include <comip.h>  // _com_ptr_t
#import "tlbname.tlb" // Change to the name of your type library


int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    ::_com_ptr_t<ISubPointer>   ptr;

    // CoISubPointer is the class ID specified in the type library
    // you will need to change the name accordingly.
    ptr.CreateInstance(__uuid(CoISubPointer), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);

    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
 }
```

When `main()` has finished `ptr` will automatically release it's reference to the `ISubPointer` object it holds.

Comment: Thank you, I see from debug that the return value of CreateInstance is "Class not registered"

Comment: If you know the class is registered double check to make sure you are calling `CreateInstance` with the class ID and not the interface id (which was originally in my answer until a quick edit)

Comment: Thanks, the interface is there as I can see in the oleview but it doesn't have a coclass, it doesn't have its own CLSID_XXX in the type library

Comment: If you know the class id you can always declare it locally `const GUID CLSID_ISubPointer = {...};`

Comment: @MilosevicTrigolos - class not registered can be a x86 vs x64 issue. Make sure the COM server you're accessing has the same bitness as the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create COM object without knowing class ID. I suggest to read the basic of COM in this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/633/Introduction-to-COM-What-It-Is-and-How-to-Use-It